# JavaScript не сортирует колонки с датой в таблице HTML

Tags: javascript, html, python, python-3.x

В таблице есть столбцы с датами, и когда я сортирую их по дате, я вижу, что они отсортированы неправильно

[image]

**app.py**

```
        software_data = []
        software_data.append(software.app_id)
        software_data.append(current_user.timezoned(software.workflow.started).\
                strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        result = {"data": software_data}
        return jsonify(result)
```

**list.html**

```
{% block page_block_content %}
    <table id="portfolio" class="portfolio table no-margin">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="appid">{{ _("AppID") }}</th>
            <th class="datetime started">{{ _("Started") }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**list.js**

```
$(function () {
    var loaders = [];
    var table = $("#portfolio").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": portfolio_data_url,
            "type": "POST"
        },

        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

        "stateSave": true,

        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "language": datatables_language,

        "order": [[ $(".portfolio thead th").index($(".portfolio thead .appid")), "desc" ]],

        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": "no-sort"
            }
        ],

        "fnInitComplete": function(){
            $("#portfolio").css("width", "100%");
        }
    })
});
```

Я думаю, что проблема в javascript, потому что есть аналогичная таблица без javascript, в котором сортировка выполнена правильно.

Comment: Питон код, который сортирует у вас не приведён (и не нужно, если не в нём проблема. Легко проверить: выполните запрос и посмотрите, что вам Питон код посылает по сети). Вы можете статический json-файл (с правильной сортировкой) c помощью любого http-сервера отправлять (или прописать фиксированное значение в коде), чтобы отладить javascript код.